# Loopback 4 include nested relations

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

Recently loopback team added support to the inclusion of nested relation. Reference https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/HasMany-relation.html#query-multiple-relations.
But it doesn't cover the rest api url to get nested relations. This is what I have tried.

> http://[::1]:3000/users?filter[include][0][relation]=carts&filter[include][0][scope]filter[include][0][relation]=product

I have three models users, carts, products. Users have has-many carts and carts belongs-to product.
My loopback/cli version is 1.27.0

user.repository.ts

```
constructor(
    @inject('datasources.farm') dataSource: FarmDataSource,  @repository.getter('CartRepository') protected cartRepositoryGetter: Getter<CartRepository>,
  ) {
    super(Users, dataSource);
    this.carts = this.createHasManyRepositoryFactoryFor('carts', cartRepositoryGetter,);
    this.registerInclusionResolver('carts', this.carts.inclusionResolver);

  }
```

cart.repository.ts

```
 constructor(
    @inject('datasources.farm') dataSource: FarmDataSource, @repository.getter('UsersRepository') protected usersRepositoryGetter: Getter<UsersRepository>, @repository.getter('ProductRepository') protected productRepositoryGetter: Getter<ProductRepository>,
  ) {
    super(Cart, dataSource);
    this.product = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor('product_id', productRepositoryGetter);
    this.registerInclusionResolver('product', this.product.inclusionResolver);

    this.users = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor('user_id', usersRepositoryGetter);
    this.registerInclusionResolver('users', this.users.inclusionResolver);
  }
}
```

product.repository.ts

```
constructor(
    @inject('datasources.farm') dataSource: FarmDataSource, @repository.getter('PurchaseRepository') protected purchaseRepositoryGetter: Getter<PurchaseRepository>, @repository.getter('StockRepository') protected stockRepositoryGetter: Getter<StockRepository>, ) {
    super(Product, dataSource);


    this.registerInclusionResolver('stocks', this.stocks.inclusionResolver);
    this.registerInclusionResolver('purchases', this.purchases.inclusionResolver);

  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully implemented relations with MySQL as the datasource. The documentation does share that using a non-relational databases will have unexpected behavior. If that's your case, then you should check out their progress.. [loopback relations open issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2341)

Our example models will be Question (Source) and Response (Target). Question has a hasMany relation with Response

**Configure your models to handle the relation, one relation at a time**

- You should add a new property to your Question model with the @hasMany decorator which will look something like this

  @hasMany(() => Response, {keyTo: 'question_id', name: 'responses'})
  responses?: Response[]
- Notice that keyTo is the foreign key that will allow the relation to work and name is just the name of the relation
- In your Question model add the foreign key property if you haven't defined it already. It can be done with the regular @property() decorator OR like the following

  @belongsTo(() => Question, {name: 'question', keyTo: 'question_id'})
  question_id?: number;

Within your source model repository (Question) you need to provide access to target model (Response) similar to the following:

```
export class QuestionRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  Question,
  typeof Question.prototype.question_id,
  QuestionRelations
  > {
  public readonly responses: HasManyRepositoryFactory<
    Response,
    typeof Question.prototype.question_id
  >;
  constructor (
    @inject('datasources.myDB') dataSource: MyDBDataSource,
    @repository.getter('ResponseRepository') responseRepository: Getter<ResponseRepository>,
  ) {
    super(Question, dataSource);
    this.responses = this.createHasManyRepositoryFactoryFor(
      'responses',
      responseRepository
    );
    this.registerInclusionResolver('responses', this.responses.inclusionResolver);
  }
}
```

- Make sure you add the last line that registers the inclusion resolver

Now your relation should be set up! To use it you would just want to create a remote method within a controller. The loopback team does communicate that a new separate controller should be created for relational cases. So in this case you would create a controller called question-response.controller.ts

Now you will just need to pass a filter object to the method you are interested in. Lets just use the .find() method since its the easiest. It should look like the following:

```
@get('/question/{questionId}/response_data')
  async findQuestionWithResponses(
    @param.path.number('questionId') questionId: typeof Question.prototype.question_id,
      @param.query.object('filter', getFilterSchemaFor(Question)) filter?: Filter<Question>
  ): Promise<any> {
    if (!filter) filter = {};
    filter.include = [{ relation: 'responses' }];
    return this.questionRepository.findById(questionId, filter);
  }
```

Hopes this helps!

Also for the nest relation it would look like the example in the documentation like the following, just make sure all your relations are set up :)

```
customerRepo.find({
  include: [
    {
      relation: 'orders',
      scope: {
        where: {name: 'ToysRUs'},
        include: [{relation: 'manufacturers'}],
      },
    },
  ],
});
```